# Flaw in Spring security OAuth2 samples: same OAuth2ClientContext used for several providers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I try to implement OAuth2 with Spring Security and I have studied the samples provided by Spring in the following Github:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/tonr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/config/WebMvcConfig.java

This OAuth2 sample is divided in two projects :

- *tonr*: OAuth2 client (OAuth2Client) and
- *sparklr*: OAuth2 provider (ResourceServer & AuthorizationServer)

Tonr allows to show photos from Sparklr and also includes a Facebook API client to list friends of an account.
It seems that once got from one provider, **the same token is sent to all OAuth2 providers**, even if the token doesn't come from the called provider.

Steps:

- I log in tonr2  (localhost:8080/tonr2/login.jsp)
- I go to Sparklr photos and log in sparklr2  (localhost:8080/tonr2/sparklr/photos & localhost:8080/sparklr2/login.jsp)
- I approve the scope Read and I see photos: OK
- Then I go to Facebook friends page : localhost:8080/tonr2/facebook/info

The **sparklr token** is sent to Facebook (visible in debug logs), and obviously Facebook returns a 400 Bad Request Error.

If now, I log out from tonr, click directly to Facebook friends page and log in tonr again, it is working; a token is asked to Facebook and access is granted.
So the same OAuth2ClientContext and same token are kept from Sparklr to Facebook.

**Question:**
How to separate *OAuth2ClientContext* to keep the token with its respective resource server?

I tried to instanciate a different OAuth2ClientContext bean for facebookRestTemplate, but the OAuth2 flow is broken with:

```
@Bean(name = "facebookClientContext")
public OAuth2ClientContext facebookClientContext() {
    return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
}

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate facebookRestTemplate(@Qualifier("facebookClientContext") OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it the same as you did except that you should:

1. inject a AccessTokenRequest (request-scoped) in the constructor of your DefaultOAuth2ClientContext. (@Resource injection is necessary in this verion of Spring because AccessTokenRequest is a Map).
2. session-scope your facebookClientContext to not share the tokens among differents users.

See OAuth2ClientConfiguration as a guideline.

Modify your WebMvcConfig$ResourceConfiguration:

```
    @Resource(name = "accessTokenRequest")
    private AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("facebookClientContext")
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public DefaultOAuth2ClientContext facebookClientContext() {
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate facebookRestTemplate(
            @Qualifier("facebookClientContext") OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), clientContext);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
                Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.valueOf("text/javascript")));
        template.setMessageConverters(Arrays.<HttpMessageConverter<?>>asList(converter));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate sparklrRestTemplate(
            @Qualifier("oauth2ClientContext") OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(sparklr(), clientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate sparklrRedirectRestTemplate(
            @Qualifier("oauth2ClientContext") OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(sparklrRedirect(), clientContext);
    }
```